# piping imagemagick output to 64 bit LSB executable

Tags: shell, imagemagick

Hey I am trying to pipe the output of 'convert' function

The line is

```sh
convert -geometry 384x \
        ../../../Flickr/balance/balance_3/balance_399.png \
        ppm:- | ./segment 0.5 2000 100 - balance_399_out.ppm
```

and throwing error.

```
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pnm_error'
 Aborted (core dumped)
```

Is there anyway to pipe output of convert to this executable without saving ppm file.

Comment: `convert rose.png ppm:- | cat > rose.ppm` works (rose.png is an imagemagick sample), maybe problem is in `segment` program or with particular file?

Comment: `segment` is a 64 bit LSB executable, do you think it may be a problem? @Andrey

Comment: can you convert the file into test.ppm and use `cat test.ppm | ./segment ...`?

Comment: Your suggestion still saves test.ppm into the directory. As I am processing multiple images, I decided to overwrite test.ppm over and over again for each image. I couldn't find a way to solve my problem.

Comment: My suggestion was not a working solution, it's for testing purposes to exclude the `convert` command from your line and check if the `segment` program can handle exactly the same file from standard input. (as for the file rewrite, you can try to write to `/dev/shm/tmp.ppm`, it is located in memory and is ultrafast)

Comment: I don't believe that error is listed on Imagemagick's [Exceptions](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/exception.php), and why bother with pipes at all? Imagemagick supports [-segement](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#segment) internally.